# Why Jetpack Compose Preview shows nothing?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-compose

I'm using Jetpack Compose and the Preview show just the title:

[image]

But if i use the dev13 version it works fine.

IDE: Android Studio 4.2 Canary 7
Compose: 0.1.0-dev17

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a known problem. [It is supposed to be fixed in Android Studio 4.2 Canary 8](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/162000445#comment4).

Comment: I'm still facing the same issue using Android Studio 4.2 Canary 13 / kotlinCompilerVersion '1.4.10' /  kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion '1.0.0-alpha03'

Answer (score 2):

In my case the problem was easy to solve. Zoom in. For some reason, after updating Android Studio, the preview did not show anything because of the zoom.

Comment: The same happened to me! Not sure why it was zoomed out to 5%!

Answer (score 1):

For anyone still looking for this in 2022

I had a spelling mistake in my dimens.xml, where I typed

```
    <dimen name="composeMinTouchTargetSize">48.dp</dimen>
```

The dot shouldn't be there. Device ignores it, Android Studio balks without error